# HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated returns false

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I have a strange issue.

I have a page with the following code.

```
if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        Server.Transfer(@"~/Views/Public/Unauthorised.aspx");
        return;
    }
```

For some reason, with one user (and we've narrowed it down to his single machine and windows logon profile), `IsAuthenticated` always returns false. Even though he is logged into the website, and can navigate to other pages that require authenticated user. Except this one page.

We checked that the machine accepts all cookies and we still get the same issue. I'm not sure where to go from here... any suggestions?

Comment: yes, all cookies are allowed. this was my first thought...

Comment: Is the domain name the same as on the pages you are logged on?

Comment: all pages are on the same domain. within the same web application, same session.

Comment: Forms or Win auth? What happens if you use a different logon on that machine?

Comment: how authentication and authorization is done? do you use FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie method? Is there any custom authorization mechanism?

Comment: it is forms authentication. they are trying a different logon on the machine now (i'm in the Uk and they are in france) waiting to here back on that now

Comment: i have used his website login credentials on my own machine and it works perfectly well. so this appears to be a local machine issue rather than a problem with the website or the code itself.

Comment: You need to identify if it is the account or the machine or the browser. Can you use the login on a different machine? Can you use a different browser on the same machine. I have seen caching do some INSANE things.

Answer (score 7):

There are at least two known cases that can make this behavior.

**First case** when you have set `requireSSL="true"` on the Authentication session on `web.config` and you call that function from a non secure page. So double check if the page is secure or not, if you use the `requireSSL="true"`

```
Debug.Assert(Request.IsSecureConnection, "The IsAuthenticated will fail.");
if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    Server.Transfer(@"~/Views/Public/Unauthorised.aspx");
    return;
}
```

**Second case** when you do not have set the `domain="site.com"` again on authentication session inside the web.config, and you try to request a cookie the one time from the `www.yoursitename.com` and the other from `yoursitename.com`. In that case the authentication cookies are different and it will fail. So set that parameter among others on web.config.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms domain="yoursitename.com"  />
</authentication>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Aristos. This damn thing was driving me nuts :) Cheers!