# IsAuthenticated is true but HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is False

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, adfs2.0

We are trying to implement Single sign on (sso) using SAML 2.0 using ADFS with our customer site.I have successfully set up ADFS and when i access ../adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon.aspx page it shows "Sign in to this site" radio button and it redirect to customer site and asks for Username and password and once entered customer's site user name and password then it brings back to idpinitiatedsignon.aspx and says "You are signed in" and shows sign out button.But i'm unable to get the logged in user's details from `HttpContext.Current.User` in idpinitiatedsignon.aspx because `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is false but `IsAuthenticated`is true. So how can i get the logged in user information ?

Comment: may be this is useful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13973756/httpcontext-current-user-identity-isauthenticated-returns-false

Comment: Is the domain name the same as on the pages you are logged on?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Which IsAuthenticated returns what? One is specified, the other not. And where do you do the IsAthenticated call? On the Application or really on the ADFS server site in IdPInitiatedSignon.aspx. What version of ADFS are you running on. What version of the Framework of the application? If it is really on ADFS, then I can probably explain it.

Comment: @paullem: It's on the ADFS server site only . i'm using adfs2.0 and our application is running on 4.0 dot net framework. Inside the IdPInitiatedSignon.aspx based on the IsAthenticated property they are enabling and disabling sign out controls so i don't know how this IsAthenticated property become True once we successfully signed in to customer site/Idp.If i know this then i can get some idea on how to read the logged in user values .

Comment: As I said in your other thread: don't do this :-). Now the explanation. ADFS is at the HttpHandler level. It should not set the Identity. The Identity must be set by an HtttpModule. ADFS is correct in not setting Identity..... And even if you could get to Identity in some weird way (as explained in the other thread) then only on S2012 and older, you would not be able to do this in the current release (on S2012R2 and later).

Answer (score 1):

Because when you call FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtUsername.Value, true); you store the key on the client's cookies. For this you need to do a response to the user. And for HttpContext.Current.User.Identity to be filled with cookie you need one more request.

In short your scheme looks like this:

- Client sends his UserName and Password.
- Server gets and checks it.
- If they are valid the server sends Set-Cookie header to the client.
- Client receives and stores it. For each request client sends cookies back to the server.